# How do I "fix" php artisan?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm using Laravel 5. Whenever I type

```
php artisan tinker
```

I get the expected output preceded by a letter c:

```
cPsy Shell v0.5.2 (PHP 5.6.10-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 — cli) by Justin Hileman
```

Same happens when I type `php artisan`

The first line I get is the following:

```
cLaravel Framework version 5.1.16 (LTS)
```

Somehow that letter is displaying on all the views I have, so is messing up my project. When I click on "View Page Source" I see the letter 'c' before the "`<!DOCTYPE html>`" but I can't find it on any of my files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this trick:

put in a controller method of your choice this code:

```
header('x-my-header: whatever');
```

If all goes well PHP will fail to send the header, and write in the error message the file and the line where the output (the "c") started.

*Note: this will not work if you're using output buffering.*

Comment: This is pretty clever. :-D

Comment: It's quite funny indeed :-))

Comment: When you do this, do you need to turn off output buffering?

Comment: You definitely should turn it off.

Comment: It didn't work for me :( I don't know If I'm disabling the output buffering the right way but I commented it on the php.ini file

Comment: try to put `@ob_end_clean();@ob_end_clean();@ob_end_clean();` at the beginning of your `index.php`

Comment: IT WORKED!! :-) THANKS! Now.. How can I make it to display the same error without writing @ob_end_clean(); at the beginning of my index.php ?

Comment: You probably have it enabled in PHP and failed to disable it. Did you restarted the webserver after changing `php.ini` ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you accidently typed "c" in the beginning of any source file that's always included (if not `artisan` itself:

```
c<?php
```

Now you can either replace the Laravel source with its original unmodified files or search for the above string, for example with:

```
rgrep  "c<?php" .
```

**On a related note:** Use a version control system like Git and you won't have these problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest opening `index.php` and check there if there is some kind of `echo "c";` or `print "c";`. As per your question and comment regarding that all your views have that letter seems like the index file or the main layout file is where the issue is. (I lean to the `index.php` file because you are seeing that letter before the doctype).

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to metion I did check the index.php file, didn't find anything there. Any workaround?